# gem 'autoprefixer-rails' does not add -ms- prefix to css

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I added gem 'autoprefixer-rails' to my Gemfile. I am noticing it adds vendor prefixes for -webkit- but I need it to also add prefixes for IE, such as -ms-.

Does anyone have any experience using this gem and actually having it generate -ms- prefixes?

https://rubygems.org/gems/autoprefixer-rails/versions/7.1.6

Comment: Did you solve your problem?